# How can I find out what pages of my site are not indexed by Googlebot?

Tags: google, google-search-console

Google Webmasters Tools show that one of pages of my site isn't indexed (it was added to the sitemap about 2 weeks ago).
How can I find out what page it is?

Comment: You can try to search indexed pages (with `site:yoursite.com` command on Google Search) and apply a difference with all your pages (depending of the number of pages you have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method to finding out what pages are index by Google is by doing:

```
site:mydomain.com
```

In a Google search. That will bring up the indexed results of your website.

Comment: You don't really answer the question.

Comment: That is my method to finding out the best results of indexed information regarding my site, even with having a cached version of it to look at when they have cached it.

Comment: The question is about finding the page NOT indexed, not the indexed pages.

Comment: The only problem with this is if you have a very big site, Google won't return all the pages using just a straight site: search.  You will have to drill down by excluding some urls, but then this isnt a guarantee to get them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary search to figure out which URLs are not indexed:

1. Split your sitemap in half into two smaller sitemaps
2. Submit each of those sitemaps
3. Repeat these steps for each sitemap that Google reports isn't fully indexed until you are down to a sitemap with just one unindexed URL in it.

Comment: I like this, pragmatic!

Answer (score 0):

You can check in Google Webmasters Tool simply go to **Search traffic** tab and find **Internal links** in its sub tab in this tab only those links will be showing which are indexed by Google.

Comment: I don't think this will work. I just checked in GWT and there are 316 internal links, yet 902 indexed.